# Generics with code block returning Unit

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following code that is working and printing "foreach executed ":

```
val buf = ArrayBuffer[() => Unit]()
def add(o: () => Unit) = buf += o
add(() => print("executed "))
print("foreach ")
buf foreach (_())
```

I would like to simplify line 3, but it breaks at first line:

```
val buf = ArrayBuffer[=> Unit]()
def add(o: => Unit) = buf += o
add { print("executed ") }
print("foreach ")
buf foreach (_)
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to store pieces of code and evaluate them later on. The `: => Type` syntax is used for passing an argument by name which means it will be evaluated each time it's referenced (instead of before passing it to a function). As far as I know, the only way to postpone evaluation is create some kind of wrapper around it and make the evaluation available through a method call. In your case a simple non argument function would be a fine wrapper:

```
val buf = ArrayBuffer[() => Unit]()
def add(o: => Unit) = buf += {() => o }
add(() => print("executed "))
print("foreach ")
buf foreach (_())
```

Comment: *Correction:* By-name parameters are _not_ lazy! They are not evaluated "when first needed," they are evaluated _every time they're referenced_ (dynamically, not statically) in the called method!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use by name values (`=>T`) as assignable objects, only as arguments to methods.
That means you cannot parametrize your `ArrayBuffer` with `=>Unit`. Your `ArrayBuffer` will have to be parametrized with `() => Unit`.

To "lift" by name values into function values, you have to use the `() => ...` syntax.
You can do the following:

```
val buf = ArrayBuffer[() => Unit]()
def add(o: => Unit) = buf += () => o
add { print("executed ") }
print("foreach ")
buf foreach (_())
```